# Comparing Sklearn with Keras -- Getting Small Error with Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am testing the code below.

```
#%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV


iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris.head()

sns.pairplot(iris, hue='species')

X = iris.values[:, 0:4]
y = iris.values[:, 4]

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.5, random_state=0)

lr = LogisticRegressionCV()
lr.fit(train_X, train_y)

pred_y = lr.predict(test_X)
print("Test fraction correct (Accuracy) = {:.2f}".format(lr.score(test_X, test_y)))
# Test fraction correct (Accuracy) = 0.93


import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils


train_y_ohe = pd.get_dummies(train_y)
test_y_ohe = pd.get_dummies(test_y)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')


loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y_ohe, show_accuracy=True, verbose=0)
print("Test fraction correct (Accuracy) = {:.2f}".format(accuracy))
```

Everything works fine until the next-to-last-line of code.

When I try to run this:

```
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y_ohe, show_accuracy=True, verbose=0)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: evaluate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'show_accuracy'
```

I did a bit of research, and found that 'show_accuracy=True' may have been depreciated a short time ago.  Is there some other way of doing this now?  How can I evaluate, and print, the accuracy of the model?

I found the code sample here:

https://blog.fastforwardlabs.com/2016/02/24/hello-world-in-keras-or-scikit-learn-versus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `show_accuracy` argument is deprecated in new versions of keras,remove this argument from `model.evaluate()` and use instead `metrics=['accuracy']` in `model.compile()`

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit model
train_y_ohe = pd.get_dummies(train_y)
model.fit(train_X, train_y_ohe,epochs=1000,batch_size=20)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y_ohe, verbose=0)
print("Test fraction correct (Accuracy) = {:.2f}".format(accuracy))

#Test fraction correct (Accuracy) = 0.97
```

Comment: Ahhh!  I see what I did wrong!  Now it makes sense, sort of.  The only issue I see now is that the accuracy with Keras is that the accuracy is around 28%.  I was expecting around 98% or 99% accuracy with the neural network model.  Any idea why the accuracy is so abysmal?  This is counter-intuitive.

Comment: You forgot to fit the model before evaluating it, I have updated my answer, with fit it get 97% accuracy

Comment: Yeap, yeap.  I see it now.  I just accommodated your change into my script.  All set now!  Thanks again!!